# Timer, click, mousedown, mouseup events not working together

Tags: c#, timer, click, mousedown, mouseup

Looking for some help on a problem Im having

sorry if this question has already been asked, I can not find anything similar.

The idea is when a picturebox is clicked changed the image to ON.

If the picture box is held for more than 2 seconds to open a new form and leave the picturebox as OFF.

However if the picturebox is clicked ON and then held for 2 seconds and then returns i need the picturebox state to remain ON.

Here is what I have tried so far.

I believe for this to work correctly I need to stop MouseUp event from occuring.

Is there a way I can stop MouseUp when Tick occurs?

Is there a easier / better way to do this?

Any help would be appreciated.

```
    private void time_HoldDownInternal_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    { 
        time_HoldDownInternal.Enabled = false;
        time_HoldDownInternal.Interval = 1000;
        form1show.Visible = true;
    }

    private void pb_pictureBoxTest_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        mainMenuVariables.mousedown = true;
        time_HoldDownInternal.Enabled = true;
    }

    private void pb_pictureBoxTest_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        mainMenuVariables.mousedown = false;
        //MessageBox.Show("mouse up");
        time_HoldDownInternal.Enabled = false;
        time_HoldDownInternal.Interval = 1000;
    }

    private void pb_pictureBoxTest_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (mainMenuVariables.mousedown == true)
        {
            if (mainMenuVariables.pictureBox == false)
            {
                mainMenuVariables.pictureBox = true;
                pb_pictureBoxTest.Image = new Bitmap(mainMenuVariables.pictureBoxOn);
                return;
            }
            if (mainMenuVariables.pictureBox == true)
            {
                mainMenuVariables.pictureBox = false;
                pb_pictureBoxTest.Image = new Bitmap(mainMenuVariables.pictureBoxOff);
                return;
            }
        }
        if (mainMenuVariables.mousedown == false)
        {
            //nothing
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Rather than starting a timer, just record the current time on mouse down. Then in mouse up, check if it has been 2 seconds. e.g:

```
private void pb_pictureBoxTest_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    mainMenuVariables.mousedown = true;
    mainMenuVariables.mousedowntime = DateTime.Now;
}

private void pb_pictureBoxTest_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    mainMenuVariables.mousedown = false;
    var clickDuration = DateTime.Now - mainMenuVariables.mousedowntime;

    if ( clickDuration > TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2))
    {
        // Do 'hold' logic (e.g. open dialog, etc)
    }
    else
    {
        // Do normal click logic (e.g. toggle 'On'/'Off' image)
    }
}
```

Comment: i will look at doing this now, but what about changing the images ON / OFF if already on or off?

Comment: @justin89 See my edit above - added a code sample based on your code.

Comment: that works great, the only thing that i would like to change is the form now opens after you let go. I would like to make the form appear a soon as the button has been held for 2 seconds

im looking at adding your code to on mousedown as well but it does not seem to be working. again thank you for all your help.

[code]
var clickDuration = DateTime.Now - mainMenuVariables.mousedowntime;

    if ( clickDuration > TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2))
    {
        // Do 'hold' logic (e.g. open dialog, etc)
    }
    else
[/code]

Comment: @justin89 Hmmm, good point. If you want it to open the dialog after 2 seconds, regardless of if the user has released the mouse button or not, you will have to use a timer. It is possible, it just is a bit more complex. I would use the same approach as above, combined with a timer. The timer tick event then launches the dialog. And in the mouse up event, simply check `if ( clickDuration < TimeSpan(2)) and do normal 'On'/'Off' image swapping.